# Cloud security scanner issues?

Tags: security-review, security-scanner

I submitted a scan yesterday : http://security.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner

Normally, I get an email informing me that the scan is put in the queue and then another mail to give me the results.

But here, I didn't get any mails. If I try to submit another scan, I get this message :

> Due to high volume, an application can only be scanned every 24 hours.
>   Please submit the application again after Jan 22, 9:23 AM. We
>   apologize for any inconvenience.

So I suppose my scan is in progress.

Do you know if there are some issues with the scanner ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no issues . Its just that scanner is under heavy load. They hove took your request and kept it in queue. It will get process when you get your turn. Dont worry it may take up to one or two days. But you will surly get result.

Comment: Ok, but why I don't get an email to inform me that my request is placed in the queue, as usual ?

Comment: When scanner is under load you may not get that. But above error clearly saying that you have submitted request in last 24 HRS.

Comment: Ok thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify how this works:

1. You submit a username + ruleset + description in the portal
   -- This creates a code scan request containing this info. No email is sent out, but the user feedback is a green bar in the UI that says the job was created successfully.
2. The scanner then picks up the code scan request and does a lot of work: it looks in the instances to find out which org and instance this user lives on. It finds the user information (e.g. email address, does the user have author apex, does the org have permission to run apex code, etc). Once the business logic checks pass, all the code is downloaded. Once the code is successfully downloaded, you get an email saying that the job is queued.
3. The scanner then processes the queued jobs by pushing code into the engines and mails out results. Here you get an email with the results.

So it's possible that you need to wait longer than usual between submitting a job and getting a notification that the job was queued. This typically means that there are some issues pulling code from the instances, and usually this happens for a period of time when we rollout API version upgrades, or the job management system itself is being serviced/upgraded.

It's also possible that for a particular user, there is a long wait between submitting a job and getting a confirmation email. This can mean that we are having some issues verifying the user or pulling code for a particular organization, even though most other users are getting fast turnarounds.

Almost all errors are intermittent in nature -- e.g. there was a timeout/server was too busy/etc. Because we auto-retry failed jobs with a backoff period, if you are a bit unlucky then you may need to wait a couple of hours before we try to pull the code again. Only after all the code is pulled do you get a confirmation email.

Comment: Just wanted to add that as of this past weekend, all the backlog is cleared up and you should get normal wait times for scans and for scan acknowledgements.